# Flex tabbed view gets reloaded every time

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4.5

I have a very simple Flex application for mobile phones which uses 3 tabs (with the `TabbedViewNavigatorApplication`).

It seems that everytime I switch tabs, the selected view is reloaded.

I've set a creationComplete command to do something and everytime I click on the tab it executes the function.

Isn't it possible for the views to get loaded 1 time and that's it?

Comment: Don't you want to show us your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me that this behaviour is exactly the point on mobile devices since you want to keep memory / cpu usage as low as possible.

This effectively means destroying all non-active views and all related view components / objects.

However you can override this default behaviour by setting the `destructionPolicy` on every view to `destructionPolicy="never"`.

[This blog post](http://corlan.org/2011/01/12/understanding-flex-mobile-views-and-viewnavigator/) will explain the basic understanding you will need to obtain.

Cheers

Comment: You're right about keeping the cpu usage as low as possible. But I have one view with a 3D container, the other views can change settings in the 3D view. Reloading the 3D view every time the app switches back to that view will take too long and is unnecessary. The desturctionPolicy worked so thanks :D

Comment: That is indeed the lone reason why I would do such a thing as well. Reloading a very complex view might take much resources / impact user perceived performance.
However changed settings could easily be stored in a `Model` which could be shared between views, so only the model and one view would be in memory at the same time.